Let Safari send Cookies when fetching a <video>
In a web app we are quite strict regarding authorization and require session cookies to be sent when using the Fetch API or loading assets via corresponding tags (<img>, <video>, …).
Now it seems that Safari (tested on 15.x, 17.x and 18.x) does not send Cookies when it fetches the <source> URL of a <video>. Thus, the browser does not play that video due to some "Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load" message.
When rendering an <img> it sends a Cookie and the image just shows fine.
Additionally, we removed authorization restrictions for that video URL in our backend and … tada … the video was playing.
Is there any known approach to make Safari send Cookies for fetching a <video> <source>?
